# Anonymous function scope confusion

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope, anonymous-function

How can I assign values inside an anonymous function to global variables, or variables outside its scope. For instance, the example below. `console.log(rows)` returns the right data, while `console.log(result)` returns undefined

```
var result;
this.query(sql).execute(function(error, rows) {
    console.log( rows )
    result = rows;
});
console.log( result );
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Node.js is event driven, meaning that most of the functions are asynchronous. The `execute` function does not return any value, because the "returned" value is in the anonymous function declared as your first argument, which function will be called only when the query has been executed and a value has been returned by the database. So your `result` variable does not contain any value, because there's nothing to return yet.

** **EDIT** **

Even after your edit, the line where you log the variable `result` is executed **before** you assign `rows` to it, because the anonymous function is only executed *later*, when the query is completed.

Comment: Changed the sample code, I had copied the incorrect code. Same result.

Comment: it won't change anything. `result` won't hold any value, simply because the anonymous function is executed *asynchronously*, meaning *later*

Comment: it's a little confusing at first, but everything comes clearer over time :)

Answer (score 0):

What does the `.execute` returns? It could be just processing the item returned by the `.query` without returning an array